# Can app use a higher Target API than the library included?

Tags: android, target, android-library

Is it possible to use a library with lower target SDK version than application's target?
Let's say our main app module has target version 26 and we use a library with target 22.
Can this library use API functions that are unavailable (was removed) in Android 26?

If so, then how is it accomplished?

Comment: If you mean deprecated api's which maybe removed in higher sdk, that won't cause problem, because  the required bytecodes is generated and placed along your libary's code in `.aar` file.

Comment: I'm asking, because Google will soon require us to use recent target API for new apps and updates. And in my apps  I use some old libraries that targets an old API and can't be compiled against the most recent API (errors about missing methods). However when I set the most recent target API in the main module of my app and I leave the old target in library gradle file, it compiles without problems.

Comment: So, you don't use `aar` file of the library and are using library source code as a dependency project in your app? In this case it is compiled with its `build.gradle` file and since you didn't change `targetSdk` there you won't have any problem. But if you have access to library source code, I suggest to try and upgarde it to support higher sdk.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you very much.